# libevent API: understanding the pointer parameters or return values

Tags: c, libevent

for the following libevent API:

```
void event_set(struct event *ev, int fd, short event, void (*cb)(int, short, void *), void *arg)

event_add(struct event *ev, const struct timeval *timeout); 

struct event* event_new (struct event_base *, evutil_socket_t, short, event_callback_fn, void)
```

I want to know:

1) for pointer parameter `ev` in the second function `event_add`, the function `event_add` makes  a local copy of the ev structure or not?

for example, if I do something like:

```
  code snippet 1:

     struct event ev;
     event_set(&ev, ..para list 1...);    // event 1 
     event_add(&ev, ...);
     event_set(&ev, ..para list 2...);    // event 2
     event_add(&ev, ...);
```

event 1 is different from event 2 because parameter list 1 is different from parameter list 2. if event_add makes a local copy, then it is no problem, but if event_add doesn't make a local copy, then these two `event_add` actually add only event 2?

besides, if I have a main function:

```
   void func(){
     struct event ev;
     event_set(&ev, ...);
     event_add(&ev, ...)
   }

   int main(){
      func();
      event_base_dispatch(base);
   }
```

after func() is called, the execution returns to main(). since `ev` is a local variable inside func(). if event_add(&ev,...) doesn't make a local copy, then `ev` is nowhere to find and there will be a problem.
so can I call event_add() on a local event structure?

I want to add many timer events(use something like evtimer_set) from time to time, and the adding happens in some callback functions. so I can't define global variabbles for the timeout events in advance, if event_add() can't be called on local variables, are there any solutions for this?

2) `event_new` returns a structure pointer, I want to know where is the structure, it is in a stack/heap memory or static memory?

**MY special case:**:

```
        in the main.c

               int main(){
                    struct event_base *base;
                    struct event pcap_ev;
                    .....                     // here I get a file descriptor pcapfd
                    event_set(&pcap_ev, pcapfd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, on_capture, pcap_handle);
                    event_base_set(base, &pcap_ev);
                    event_add(&pcap_ev, NULL);
                    .....
                    event_base_dispatch(base);
               }

         on_capture callback function:
                void *on_capture(int pcapfd, short op, void *arg)
                {
                 pcap_t *handle;
                 handle = (pcap_t *)arg;
                 fqueue_t* pkt_queue;

                 pkt_queue = init_fqueue();
                 pcap_dispatch(handle, -1, collect_pkt, pkt_queue);  // this function put all the cached packets into pkt_queue
                 process_pcap(pkt_queue);
                }

          the sub-routine process_pcap():

                void process_pcap(pkt_queue);{
                      for (pkt in pkt_queue){      // here is pseudo code
                           insert(table, pkt);     // here insert the pkt into a certain table 
                           struct event pkt_ev;
                           evtimer_set(&pkt_ev, timer_cb, NULL);  // I want to call timer_cb after timeout
                           event_base_set(base, &pkt_ev);
                           event_add(&pkt_ev, timeout);                     
                      }
                }

         the callback function timer_cb():

                timer_cb(...){
                     if(...)  delete(table, pkt);
                     .......
                }
```

I'm just afraid `timer_cb()` won't be called because `pkt_ev` is a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a different `struct event` instance for each event you want to know about. You can only call `event_add()` on a local `struct event` variable if that variable has a lifetime that spans across all calls to the event loop API up until it is removed with `event_del()`.

The allocation functions default to the heap, but you can substitute your own allocation routines in its place with `event_set_mem_functions()`.

Comment: `You must use a different struct event instance for each event you want to know about.`， why? the event_add() doesn't make a local copy?

Comment: I updated my question, if the event_add() doesn't make a local copy, then if it is called on a local `struct event` variable inside a sub-function, it will cause problems?

Comment: if struct event is local and non-static(not inside a function where the event_loop function), how can its lifetime spans across all calls to the event loop API(`event_base_dispatch()`)? a non-static local variable's lifetime is just inside the function where it is defined.

Comment: It seems to me that I need to create global variables for each event. I want to add many timer events(use something like `evtimer_set`) from time to time, and the adding happens in some callback functions. so I can't define global variabbles for the timeout events in advance, are there solutions for this? thanks!

Comment: For dispatch, I meant if the dispatch was happening in the same function. For the timers, you should associate back to some event context object when you get your callback. In my code, I typically have one such object per connection. This "connection object" contains all the other things I would want to set/unset, like timers and such.

Comment: sorry, I want to make it more clear. so you meant if the struct event variable is local, it should be defined in the same function where `event_base_dispatch()` or `event_base_loop` is defined?

Comment: Just don't try to do it. You should just always use `event_new()`.

Comment: for the timer stuff, I don't get your idea. I need to define many events, and these events may be in parallel, they are not sequential. if sequential(one by one), I can just reuse events.

Comment: Each concurrent event should have an associated `struct` that you put in the things that are relevant to that connection. Each struct could have its own timer. See the `cmdsocket` in [this example](https://github.com/nitrogenlogic/cliserver/blob/master/cliserver.c).

Comment: event_new is in version 2.0? I'm using 1.4.xxx, just `struct event ev` and then `event_set` could replace `event_new`. But what I asked is not about `event_new`. I'm just afraid if `event_add()` is called on a local `struct event`, this event will not be dispatched or abnormally dispatched.

Comment: Create one `struct event` per connection. If you know that you will only support a maximum number of connections, you can create an array of that number. Then, create a way to allow you to associate an `fd` to the `struct event` when you create one to handle the new connection.

Comment: it is not about per-connections. The problem is I can't estimate the number of events in advance. so I have to create one event each time a call back function or its sub-function wants to insert an event into the event_loop. libevent is unflexible in this regard.....

Comment: Since you are only describing your problem generally, I can only describe a solution generally. If you post a more specific question, I (or someone else) may be able to give you a better answer. But, I am pretty sure I have answered this particular question that you have posted.

Comment: I have added my special example, can you have a look, thanks!

Comment: I got a solution, that is to create struct event using malloc. But I'm at a loss on when to free it after the event is used. Can I free it inside the event callback function?

Comment: You can free it after calling `event_del()`.

Comment: If I don't use PERSIST flag, then the event is excuted for only once and I don't need to explicity call event_del(). MY new question is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691188/libevent-is-it-allowed-to-free-an-event-inside-its-callback-function-if-the-eve