# libevent: is it allowed to free an event inside its callback function if the event is created by malloc

Tags: c, linux, libevent

I need to create events using `malloc`, but I'm at a loss where to free them, I'm wondering 
whether it is allowed to free an event inside its callback function, like:

```
struct event *pkt_ev = (struct event *)malloc(sizeof(struct event));
evtimer_set(&pkt_ev, timer_cb, &pkt_ev);    
event_base_set(base, &pkt_ev); 
event_add(&pkt_ev, timeout);
```

the callback function timer_cb():

```
    timer_cb(int fd, short ev, void* arg){
    .......
    free(arg);    // here the arg is &pkt_ev
}
```

my initial thinking is:  after the callback function `timer_cb()` is called, the libevent will implicitly call `event_del(&pkt_ev)`. But since I freed `&pkt_ev` inside the callback, there will be a crash/exception on `event_del(&pkt_ev)`. is it right?

however, if `event_del(&pkt_ev)` doesn't care what content `pkt_ev` points to, it might not be a problem?

besides, in this function:

```
        event_add(struct event *ev, struct timeval *timeout);
```

the content pointed by `ev` should be cared a lot, generally it should be a global variable or its lifetime should cover the event loop(namely, when the event loop function is running, it will access the content pointed by `ev`). How about the content pointed by timeout? should the content pointed by timeout cover the event loop?

Answer (score 0):

You first assumption is wrong, libevent implicitly calls `event_del()` **before** invoking the callback function, not **after** (given that the EV_PERSIST flag isn't set). So there is no issue freeing pkt_ev in a callback if the EV_PERSIST flag is not set. If it is set, you need to explicitely call `event_del()` first.

Regarding your second question, no, the content pointed by timeout is copied before `event_add()` returns.